# PHP Form passing values via URL

Tags: php, forms

I have a login page (local intranet so dont worry about the security issues).
This page consists of the following form code  :

```
<form action="auth.php" method="get" class="blocklogin">    
<tr>
<td class="blocklogin" ><div align="left">Username:&nbsp; <input class="blocklogin"     type="text" name="username" id="username" /><br />
</div></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td class="blocklogin" ><div align="left">Password: &nbsp;  <input class="blocklogin"         type="password" name="password" id="password" />
</div></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" class="blockloginfoot" title="Login"><input name="Login" type="submit"     value="Login" /></td>
</form>
```

Now im trying to pass the username and password via the http link by doing the following :

```
http://localhost/folder/user_login.php?username=user@test&password=test123
```

But this does not seem to work,its suppose to use the details in the link to login. Am I missing something?
Pls help

The form action auth.php

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once('database.php');


$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];



$sql = "SELECT * FROM access_getaccountswithinfo WHERE username='".$username."' AND     password='".$password."'";

$run = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($run);

if (mysql_num_rows($run) == 1) {
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $row['password'];
$_SESSION['packagename'] = $row['packagename'];
$_SESSION['creation-date'] = $row['creation-date'];
$_SESSION['cap'] = $row['cap'];
$_SESSION['total'] = $row['total'];
$_SESSION['remainingtopup'] = $row['remainingtopup'];


header("location: usage.php");
} else {
header("location: user_login.php");

}


 mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Database code - database.php :

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'dbase', 'pass123');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

// make dbase the current db
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('dbase', $link);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: updated question with the form action auth.php

Comment: any more suggestions guys? pls

Comment: Precisely what is not working?  If you add `print_r($_GET);` what do you see?  From the looks of it, the issue may be with your database code.

Comment: @PassKit , ok added database code to bottom of my Question. Works 100% when logging in normal via the login page , but not when trying to pass the username and password in the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using URL passing values to user_login.php where the form is...you have to pass it to auth.php which is the php that actually captures the values as follow

```
http://localhost/folder/auth.php?username=user@test&password=test123
```

Answer (score 0):

If you try via url:

http://yourserver.com/folder/user_login.php?username=user@test&password=test123

You should use `$_GET['username']` and `$_GET['password']` to retrieve the value.

Otherwise if you submitting it, use `$_POST['username']` and `$_POST['password']`

May this help.

Comment: You likely seems forget </form> at your input form. Check out it.

Comment: its there :) , else using the normal login wouldnt have worked

Answer (score 0):

Your html form uses the method "post" to send the data to your php script. Post data is sent in the header and the setup you have now should work.

When doing it via url you can get the parameters using "$_GET", not "$_POST".

Also, remember to htmlspecialchars() what you send from the form.

Comment: tried with $_GET now and doesnt work...could you explain more about the htmlspecialchars() pls

Comment: ok did with specialchar as wel and still not working: 

    $username = htmlspecialchars($_GET['username'], ENT_QUOTES);